# query lookups in django using a models attribute attributes

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have an `Image` model that has an `ImageField`

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="pictures")
    #some other speicific to model fields
```

I want to be able to look for an Image when what I know is the name of it (which is unique). E.g if you have `MEDIA_ROOT` set to `path_to_media` and you upload image.jpg to pictures under MEDIA_ROOT then image.jpg is stored under `path_to_media/pictrues/image.jpg` and `pictures/image.jpg` becomes the name of the image like

```
image = Image.objects.get(pk=1) #if the image has id 1
print image.image.name #that prints pictures/image.jpg according to the example above
```

I want to be able to get the image when I have the name of it which is unique. So I have

```
name = "pictures/image.jpg"
image = Image.objects.get(image__name=name)
```

But this won't do it. What I get is the following error message:

```
FieldError: Join on field 'image' not permitted. Did you misspell 'name' for the lookup type?
```

How can I query to get a model based on a attribute of each own field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
name = "pictures/image.jpg"
image = Image.objects.get(image=name)
```

or

```
image = Image.objects.get(image="pictures/image.jpg")
```

Comment: yes I edited my answer, It can be closed :) Thanks for answering

Comment: You welcome :) Your Question description was so clear, any one could had understood it .